# Can a thread be preempt while holding a pthread lock?

Tags: linux, kernel, posix

When a pthread holding a lock(mutex or rwlock or spinlock), it can be preempted?
I read kernel code, when holding a lock of kernel, it cannot be preemted, is that right?

Comment: Is the question about locks in the kernel code or in the user-space code? "pthread lock" is a *user-space* lock, so whatever you read about the Linux kernel is inapplicable to it.

Comment: Yes, pthread lock is a user-space lock.

Answer (score 1):

*When a pthread holding a lock(mutex or rwlock or spinlock), it can be preempted ?* No, it can't be preempted in case of **non preemptive kernel**.

In case of **preemptive kernel**, *forced process switch* will happen if any high priority job came & process running in kernel mode can be replaced by another process while in the middle of a kernel function.

Comment: Thanks. If there are no high priority processes, it can be preempted by another pthread?

Comment: Let's say a procees job is to execute the exception handler & time allocated for that process is expired but job is not done, in this case if your kernel is `preemptive` then that process will replaced immediately by another. And if your kernel is `nonpreemptive` then that process will continue to run until job finish or it can voluntarily relinquish the CPU.

Comment: It means that userspace lock dose not modify thread's preempt_count in kernel, so that thread can be preempted?